# Get all key/value from nsmutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am having `NSMutableArray` like :

```
array : (
{
     a = "1";
}
{
     b = "2";
}
)
```

i want to assign all this key value to my `UILabel` how can i?

Comment: have you display in tableview

Comment: no, it's a uiview which having labels

Comment: how many label there

Comment: can you show your code how to add the nsmutablearray

Comment: [RsiArray addObject:responseObject]; by this i have added response object (i am using AFNetworking). and i am having about 15 label to display.

Comment: can you count the response object value. nslog the response object

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116870/discussion-between-harikrishnan-p-and-ios-developer).

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve by doing this..

```
for(NSDictionary *dicValue in array){
    //Get all the keys of the dictionary
    NSArray *keys=[dicValue allKeys];

    //Now loop into keys and get the values

    for(NSString *key in keys){
         //Your Value here

        NSString *value=[dicValue valueForKey:key];

        NSLog(@"Key = %@ - Value = %@",key,value);


    }

}
```

**Update**

I just ran my code with your data below

> NSArray *array=@[@{ @"Stoch" : @"31.474"}, @{ @"CCI" : @"-80.000"}, @{
>   @"William R" : @"-73.005" }, @{ @"macd" : @"-1.119"}, @{
>   @"adx":@"14.087"}, @{@"bear_power": @"-0.0133", @"bull_power" :
>   @"-0.0015" }, @{ @"roc" : @"-2.4884"}, @{ @"RSI": @"41.166"}, @{
>   @"atr":@"0.0108"}, @{ @"ultimate oscillator": @"49.913"},
>   @{@"stochrsi" :@"0.203"}];

I got this output

```
Key = Stoch - Value = 31.474
Key = CCI - Value = -80.000
Key = William R - Value = -73.005
Key = macd - Value = -1.119
Key = adx - Value = 14.087
Key = bull_power - Value = -0.0015
Key = bear_power - Value = -0.0133
Key = roc - Value = -2.4884
Key = RSI - Value = 41.166
Key = atr - Value = 0.0108
Key = ultimate oscillator - Value = 49.913
Key = stochrsi - Value = 0.203
```

Hope it helps.

Cheers.

Comment: is it maintain order of all key ? because from the value how can i know which that which value will goto which label?

Comment: No it won't but you can always write sort descriptor on keys if you want to get it in sorted way.

Comment: not in a sorted way. but i want value as it's in responseobject order.

Comment: Only keys array won't be sorted but the main `NSMutableArray` will be sorted, you should try it first see what happens.

Comment: @iosdeveloper I checked your data with the code I written check my update.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to assign all key's and values to label

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
  NSMutableArray *arrayLabelKey;
  NSMutableArray *arrayLabelValue;
  int lblYHeight;

}

@end

@implementation ViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
   arrayLabelKey = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
   arrayLabelValue = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
   lblYHeight = 200; //Intially I set label Y position is 200
}

for(int i=0;i<array.count;i++)
{
   for(NSString *strKey  in [[array objectAtIndex:i]allKeys])
   {
      [arrayLabelKey addObject:[self checkEmpty:strKey]];  //check strKey is empty or not with below method,because if string null or lenght=0 it crashes here.So that I call that below method.Now it does not crash.
   }
   for(NSString *strValue  in [[array objectAtIndex:i]allValues])
   {
      [arrayLabelValue addObject:[self checkEmpty:strValue]];  //check strValue is empty or not with below method,,because if string null or lenght=0 it crashes here.So that I call that below method.Now it does not crash.
   }
}
```

Check whether string is empty or not

```
- (void)checkEmpty:(NSString *)check
{
  @try 
  {
    if (check.length==0)
     check = @" ";

    if([check isEqual:[NSNull null]])
     check = @" ";
  }
  @catch (NSException *exception) 
  {
     check = @" ";
  }
}
```

Now creating dynamic label according to the array count

```
for(int j = 0; j<arrayLabelKey.count;j++)
{
  //Key label
  UILabel *labelKey = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, y, 100, 50)];
  labelKey.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrayLabelKey objectAtIndex:j]];
  [self.view addSubview:labelKey];

  //Colan label
  UILabel *labelColan = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160, y, 2, 50)];
  [self.view addSubview:labelColan];

  //Value label
  UILabel *labelValue = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(170, y, 100, 50)];
  labelValue.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrayLabelValue objectAtIndex:j]];
  [self.view addSubview:labelValue];

  y=y+30;
}
```